# Android - MaterialDrawer when bakc press go back activity instead closing drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawer, materialdrawer

I am using MaterialDrawer from:
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

and when the user presses the back button, the app goes one activity backwards, instead of just closing the drawer.

is it a bug or there is a way to fix it?

Comment: post your code then we can help you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. If you want to close Drawer on Back press, you have to override the `onBackPressed()` function.

First get a reference to your **`DrawerLayout`** :

```
DrawerLayout myDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_drawer);
```

Then override the **`onBackPressed()`** function to close drawer when it is open instead of closing activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (myDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        myDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } 
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

just close your drawer if it is open on pressing back button

```
@override
public void onBackPressed(){
  //DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  DrawerLayout drawerLayout = result.getDrawerLayout();      
  if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
    //drawer is open
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START); 
    //result.closeDrawer();     
  }
}
```

Comment: not working. this is why I mentioned I'm using https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer drawer and not the regular android one, sinve there is no drawer_layout object in this library

Comment: result.closeDrawer();   can solve your problem. where result is an object of Drawer.

Comment: edited now check, but just make sure what comes after typing after the "result."  for the checking the if drawer is open or not.  Just try to change if condition.